how to get the autocomplete list above every thing or at the same level of the auto-complete control
i'm using angular prime-ng and used with it the mat-autocomplete.
I already used it and it worked fine but when i reused it in  a prime-ng sidebar and i click on the form field the list of choices it shows under or behind the sidebar.
I want to show the list at the same level of my control

My code snippet is below  ( the autocomplete code is another component and it's injected inside the sidebar in #injectedComponentHere) :
this is the autocomplete code :
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Pick one"
               aria-label="Number"
               matInput
               [formControl]="myControl"
               [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
          @for (option of filteredOptions_ | async; track option) {
            <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
          }
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>

and this is the code for the sidebar :
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
        <p-sidebar modal="false"  #sidebarRef [(visible)]="sidebarVisible"                          [style]="{width:'80%'}">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2">
                    
                    <span class="font-bold">
                        <i class="pi pi-face-smile"></i>
                        User managments
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
             <div class="row grid">
            <div class="col-3" style="background-color: #fff;">
                <!-- SOME CONTROLS -->
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-9" id="hello-component-host" style="background-color:#d9d9d938;">
                  <ng-template #injectedComponentHere></ng-template> 
            </div>
          </div>
       </p-sidebar>
  </div>


Can you share your code (ts/html/css) ?

thank you for the respond.
I have just edited the poste and added the code

i found a solution in scss file:
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
z-index: 10001 !important;
}

I found a solution in scss file:
  ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 10001 !important;
  }

